# Diminutive for "решето" and "загадка"

Tags: словоупотребление

I am looking for a nickname/affectionate name for a character in a story that I am writing. I was considering basing it upon the word 'riddle' or 'puzzle' Are these the proper translations? `Решето` and `загадка`. Is there a diminutive form for each? I tried reading about how to choose the proper suffixes but my understanding of Russian is too limited to work it out.

Comment: @V.V. Решето is listed as one of possible translations of word riddle: загадка; тайна; загадочный человек; решето; грохот; сито; щит; экран; трудная проблема

Comment: Is the character male or female?

Comment: To understand the meaning of russian noun, it is often useful to search it at google image.

Comment: @Artemix It must be mentioned that riddle (загадка) and riddle (решето - и, возможно, не кухонное решето, cf. A large coarse sieve, especially one used for separating ashes from cinders or sand from gravel.- OLDonline) are homonyms. These two words are not related at all (except they are homonyms of course).

Comment: Here is agricultural (or industrial) riddle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddle_(tool) , while решето in Russian is most likely a kitchen item (i.e. sieve).

Answer (score 7):

Решето is a household item - a sieve. Better synonyms are загадка, головоломка, ребус, шарада. Diminutives are загадочка, головоломочка, ребусик, шарадочка.

As for gender - only ребус is masculine noun, while загадка, шарада, головоломка are feminine nouns.

Comment: Решето: http://cdn01.ru/files/users/images/4a/65/4a658da49cbd31b5651033fea33706da.jpg

Comment: @Tamz That's great! Then mark this answer as "accepted" (it's a checkmark under the answer vote count).

Comment: And out of these, Шарадочка is the only one that could make a credible nickname.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I would want it to be credible. That is important to me. I try to take great care when choosing character names.

Comment: One more query...can you make Барсук a diminutive? That is his current nickname. Thank you.

Comment: @Tamz It's Барсучок

Comment: @Tamz And this is what I was talking about. *Барсучок* as a nickname sounds awkward and artificial.

Comment: By the way, I had a colleague that had a nickname Барсук. I guess that nobody of his male colleagues in sound mind would call him "Барсучок" (however maybe this would sound ok, if he would be called that way by a woman he loves?). Another one was known as Кот, and I heard many times when he was called Котик by his women colleagues.

Comment: Thank you all for the input. No, I think  Барсучок is not what I'm after.I will have to keep looking. I appreciate the prompt replies though this is a great site.

Comment: "Барсучок" is perfectly fine for a young child. A teenager would be deeply embarrassed to be called like that.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question:

"Решетечко" - a word rarely used. Something that can be said to a 3 years old, or to deliberately create humor.

"Загадочка" - a more widely used word. Can be used in virtually all diminutive contexts.

As person's nicknames, both look unlikely, but not impossible.

Comment: also решетишко & загадонька

Comment: @Баян Купи-ка yes, right. But also quite rare.